# jQuery IE Compatibility Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/np3yw04t/), it works fine in `mozilla` and `chrome`, but when I open it in `IE` the stalker doesn't work anymore.

Here's my `jQuery Code:`

```
var stalker = $('.stalker');
var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), gradient, initialized = false;
$("#container").mousemove(function(e){
  setTimeout(function(){
    initialized = true;
    canvas.width  = stalker.width();
    canvas.height = stalker.height();
    gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(e.pageX, e.pageY, 0, e.pageX, e.pageY, canvas.width);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, stalker.css('border-top-color'));
    gradient.addColorStop(1, stalker.css('border-bottom-color'));
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }, initialized ? 200 : 0);
});
```

Comment: What version of IE, what version of jQuery? What does "*the stalker doesn't work [any more]*" mean, exactly?

Comment: Works perfectly fine on IE11 for me at least ?

Comment: @DavidThomas "Internet explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or activex controls" just prompt me this... I just allowed block contents... why is that happening?

Comment: I am using IE11 too.. but when I run my index.html file it prompts me this message `Internet explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or activex controls`.. I just click the allowed from blocking button and it works fine..

Comment: sounds like you are trying to load `http` resources in `https` page

Comment: @charlietfl some of my resources were from `cdn`... does that explain the ` Internet explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or activex controls`?

Comment: are you on https page? Most CDN's will deliver from either https or http and you can remove protocol from `src` like `src="//someCdn.com/path/to/file"`

Comment: Yes sample of my resources ` <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">`.. I'll try your solution.

Comment: @charlietfl still the same... I tried to get the jquery in my local... and all my css have no https anymore... it still prompts me... I think maybe because I'm running it local?